# date filter not wroking for mysql in php

Tags: php

Table name :- add_user 

data is inserting in it, there is a column **due_date** storing date in **(dd-mm-yyyy) format**
now i want to create a filter for due_date. But my code is not working. When i'm running the code it is showing all data, it is not filtering it.

**here is my code**

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
  <label> <b>From Date :&ensp; </b></label>
  <input type="date" name="s_date" class="form-control">&emsp;
<input type="date" name="e_date" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
  </form>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once "config2.php";
if(count($_POST)>0) {

$s_date=date("dd-mm-yyyy", strtotime($_POST['s_date']));

$e_date=date("dd-mm-yyyy", strtotime($_POST['e_date']));
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM add_user WHERE due_date BETWEEN '$s_date' AND '$e_date'");
}
?>

    <center>
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
  <th>Action</th>
  <th>Pet Photo</th>
<th>Owner</th>
<th>Mobile Number</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Pet Id</th>
<th>Pet Name</th>
<th>Address</th>

</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<tr>

  <td><a href="profile3.php?pet_id=<?php echo $row["pet_id"];?>"><button class="btn btn-info">View</button></a></td>

  <td><img src="/pet_img/<?php echo $row["signature"]; ?>"width="60px"height="80px"> </td>
<td><img src="/pet_img/<?php echo $row["photo"]; ?>"width="60px"height="80px"> <br><b> <?php echo $row["name"]; ?> </td>

<td><?php echo $row["mobile"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["type"]; ?></td>

<td><b><font color="green"><?php echo $row["pet_id"]; ?></font></b></td>
<td><?php echo $row["pet_name"]; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row["add1"]; ?> <?php echo $row["add2"]; ?> <?php echo $row["add3"]; ?> <?php echo $row["pin"]; ?></td>
</tr>


<?php
$i++;
}
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `dd-mm-yyyy` format isn't appropriate for ordering.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings rather than `DATE`?

Comment: If you want to be able to order date strings, they should be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: Can you show the table data and structure of table?

Answer (score 0):

Your column data type needs to be either timestamp or date/datetime. You can't compare date strings in this format.